# Creating a reset button

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have a sheet where i can put in number and mark check boxes when I have put in a number and it calculates what i need. But its always a hassle removing all the inputs and check marks when I am starting a New order. I did find a function that could clear cells, but that cleared everything, and that's no good unfortunately.

So my question is, does anyone know a way to make either a check box or a button that u can press to clear specific cells and check marks?

Comment: This should be easy with App Script. Using `OnEdit` and the `uncheck()` method for `Ranges` this should be easy to implement. If you could share a copy of your spreadsheet, we will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome!

There are several easy ways to get this job done. One of them is [**macro** (see *Automate tasks in Google Sheets*)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004).

Step by step:

1. Start macro recording, make sure "Use absolute references" is selected in the recorder settings

[image: Recorder settings]

2. Select the first input cell in your form and clear it
3. Now copy this empty cell to clear the clipboard
4. Select the other cells and ranges you want to clear and paste this
   blank value
5. Select the first input cell again and end the macro recording
6. Give the macro a meaningful name
7. Fill out the form and test the macro

[image: Record Macro]

Comment: Ah this is clever! Would it be better to set this is as an absolute reference, so that he can run the macro, wherever he's cursor* is? *the blue outline

Comment: @DavidTan Yes, you are right - this should have been mentioned, I added the first step of the instruction.